# Using data.table::setnames() when some column names might not be present

Tags: r, data.table

I have a script returning a `data.table` which will contain a set of columns. I'd like to rename some of these columns, but `setnames` breaks if not all are present. Is there any way to rename without looping+error catching or intersecting against existing names?

```
iris.dt <- data.table(iris)
# First time works fine
setnames(iris.dt, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), c("length", "width"))
# Second time fails because columns no longer exist
setnames(iris.dt, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), c("length", "width"))
# Error in setnames(iris.dt, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), c("length",
# :Items of 'old' not found in column names: Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width
```

Something like `setnames(..., allow=T)` would be ideal.

**Edit**: Filed this as a [FR on Github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1099).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of `data.table` v1.12.0 (13 Jan 2019), this is an argument to `setnames`:

```
setnames(..., skip_absent=TRUE)  # FALSE by default.
```

Answer (score 5):

This revised `setnames` function did the trick:

```
Setnames <- function(x, old, new, allow.absent.cols=F) {
  if (!allow.absent.cols) {
    setnames(x, old, new)
  } else {
    old.intersect <- intersect(old, names(x))
    common.indices <- old %in% old.intersect
    new.intersect <- new[common.indices]
    setnames(x, old.intersect, new.intersect)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try "one-liner"

```r
library(data.table)
iris.dt <- data.table(iris)

setnames(iris.dt,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")[names(iris.dt) %chin% c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], c("length", "width")[names(iris.dt) %chin% c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")])
```

You can use `old` and `new` as input variables.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach adapted from arunsrinivasan's suggestion on the [Github FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1099#issuecomment-88637025):

```
Setnames <- function(x, old, new, allow.absent.cols=F) {
  if (!allow.absent.cols) {
    setnames(x, old, new)
  } else {
    ix <- match(names(x), old, 0L)
    setnames(x, old[ix], new[ix])
  }
}
```