# Function error in R "setnames"

Tags: r

I made an upgrade in R, and since then, I have a lot of errors in programs which were working well before. 
The one I cannot go around is :

```
Error: could not find function "setnames"
```

I am loading the packages (

```
library(plyr)
library(dtplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lsr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stats)
```

and i am using R :
platform       x86_64-w64
major          3
minor          3.2

Does anybody knows how to go around please ?

Comment: There is one `setnames()` function in package `data.table`

Comment: You need to post your code and say what is being done, preferably with reproducible version of data objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a typo, if you're referring to `setNames` in `stats`.

Remember to capitalize the 'n'.

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html

(The other possibility is that you may not have loaded the `data.table` package. See, for example, [Using data.table::setnames() when some column names might not be present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380447/using-data-tablesetnames-when-some-column-names-might-not-be-present))

Comment: Hi, It was indeed the data.table package missing. THANK YOU.

Comment: Thanks, hope it helped! More importantly, welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: Also, if I answered your question well enough, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer. Don't feel obliged though.

Comment: Hi wwl, sure where/how do I accept the answer pls

Comment: Click the button with the tick (at the left hand side, below the vote count) and it should turn green

Comment: Cool, done, THANK YOU wwl.